# Extra white space appearing along sides of HTML blast

Tags: html, email, outlook, newsletter

I am having an HTML and Outlook 2007 problem with a few variations.

I have two blasts which are built with HTML, inline styling, Notepad, and tested using Email on Acid.

Our email blast software is Critical Impact.

Outlook 2007 is displaying one of our newsletters with a lot of extra white space on both sides of the blast:

[Joan's Outlook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x09kJ.jpg)

Yet this is how it looks in my Outlook 2007:

[Mary's Outlook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFAAZ.jpg)

Both of us are on Windows 7.

Email on Acid shows the blast as it looks in my Outlook.

I need to find out what is causing all of that extra white space.

The coding for this blast is the same across the board.

Is the problem in my HTML or in Outlook?

Comment: It could be anything. You should show us a part of your code and css.

Comment: <style type="text/css">table {border-collapse: collapse;}</style>
</head>
<body>
<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" width="700" style="table-layout: fixed">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<p style="text-align: center"><span style="font-family:Verdana; font-size:11px">To view this email in your browser, please click <a href="http://www.mlo-online.com/Labline/201512/16/toc.htm" style="text-decoration:none; color:Blue">here.</a><br>
 %%fwtf%% </span></p>
</td></tr>

</tbody>
</table>